# Export Excel table to relationship tables MySQL

Tags: mysql, excel, export

I have these tables in my MySQL database :

> **User** ( ID, Name, ID_country )
>
> **Countries** (ID, country_name )

And in Excel I have just like this table :

```
╔════╦═════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║  Name   ║  Country  ║
╠════╬═════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ Yamashi ║ Japon     ║
║  2 ║ Mary    ║ Australie ║
╚════╩═════════╩═══════════╝
```

I have a hundred lines in excel, and I want to export them into MySQL, using **Load csv data** it's will be simple if I have the same tables in MySQL database and Excel table.
So what is the best way to do this ? Any advice would be welcome! thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First load all your csv data into a new temporary sql  (**temp_table** (ID, Name, Country)) table. then to fill countries table execute this:

```
INSERT INTO Countries (country_name)
SELECT DISTINCT Country FROM temp_table
```

then fill your User table with this query:

```
INSERT INTO User (ID,Name)
SELECT ID,Name FROM temp_table
```

lastly, to create the relation between countries and user do this:

```
UPDATE User,temp_table,Country SET ID_country = Countries.ID WHERE User.ID = temp_table.ID AND temp_table.Country = Countries.Country
```

if everything looks ok, you can now safely remove temp_table

```
DROP TABLE temp_table
```

Comment: make sure to come back and vote/accept if this works for you ;)